# CloseableHttpAsyncClient terminates with ConnectionClosedException: Connection closed unexpectedly

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpasyncclient

I am working on a file downloader that submits get requests for around thousand files. I came across [this article](http://www.baeldung.com/httpasyncclient-tutorial) that would aid in submitting a lot of requests using the executor framework. I tried running a smaller number of files (around a hundred), it was working. However, the large number of files that I ran resulted in ConnectionClosedException.

This is the download code that submits the requests:

```
void download(String sObjname, List<FileMetadata> blobList) throws IOException, InterruptedException
{
    long totalSize = 0;
    this.sObjname = sObjname;
    for (FileMetadata doc : blobList)
    {
        totalSize += doc.getSize();
        doc.setStatus(JobStatus.INIT_COMPLETE);
    }
    totalFileSize = new AtomicLong(totalSize);

    // Async client definiton; MAX_CONN around 5-15
    try (CloseableHttpAsyncClient httpclient = HttpAsyncClients.custom().setMaxConnPerRoute(MAX_CONN)
            .setMaxConnTotal(MAX_CONN).build())
    {
        httpclient.start();

        // Define the callback for handling the response and marking the status
        FutureCallback<String> futureCallback = new FutureCallback<String>() {

            @Override
            public void cancelled()
            {
                logger.error("Task cancelled in the rest client.");
                shutdownLatch.countDown();
            }

            @Override
            public void completed(String docPath)
            {
                FileMetadata doc = futureMap.get(docPath);
                logger.info(doc.getPath() + " download completed");
                totalFileSize.addAndGet(-1 * doc.getSize());
                doc.setStatus(JobStatus.WRITE_COMPLETE);
                shutdownLatch.countDown();
            }

            @Override
            public void failed(Exception e)
            {
                shutdownLatch.countDown();
                logger.error("Exception caught under failed for " + sObjname + " " + e.getMessage(), e);
                Throwable cause = e.getCause();
                if (cause != null && cause.getClass().equals(ClientProtocolException.class))
                {
                    String message = cause.getMessage();
                    // TODO Remove this
                    logger.error("Cause message: " + message);
                    String filePath = message.split("Unable to download the file ")[1].split(" ")[0];
                    futureMap.get(filePath).setStatus(JobStatus.WRITE_FAILED);
                }
            }

        };


        // Submit the get requests here
        String folderPath = SalesforceUtility.getFolderPath(sObjname);
        new File(new StringBuilder(folderPath).append(File.separator).append(Constants.FILES).toString()).mkdir();
        String body = (sObjname.equals(Constants.contentVersion)) ? "/VersionData" : "/body";
        shutdownLatch = new CountDownLatch(blobList.size());
        for (FileMetadata doc : blobList)
        {
            String uri = baseUri + "/sobjects/" + sObjname + "/" + doc.getId() + body;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(uri);
            httpGet.addHeader(oauthHeader);
            doc.setStatus(JobStatus.WRITING);

            // Producer definition
            HttpAsyncRequestProducer producer = HttpAsyncMethods.create(httpGet);

            // Consumer definition
            File docFile = new File(doc.getPath());
            HttpAsyncResponseConsumer<String> consumer = new ZeroCopyConsumer<String>(docFile) {
                @Override
                protected String process(final HttpResponse response, final File file,
                        final ContentType contentType) throws Exception
                {
                    if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.SC_OK)
                    {
                        throw new ClientProtocolException("Unable to download the file " + file.getAbsolutePath()
                                + ". Error code: " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() + "; Error message: "
                                + response.getStatusLine());
                    }
                    return file.getAbsolutePath();
                }

            };

            // Execute the request
            logger.info("Submitted download for " + doc.getPath());
            httpclient.execute(producer, consumer, futureCallback);
            futureMap.put(doc.getPath(), doc);
        }

        if (futureMap.size() > 0)
            schedExec.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerRunnable, 0, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

        logger.debug("Waiting for download results for " + sObjname);
        shutdownLatch.await();

    }
    finally
    {
        schedExec.shutdown();
        schedExec.awaitTermination(24, TimeUnit.HOURS);
        logger.debug("Finished downloading files for " + sObjname);
    }
}
```

The stacktrace that I received was:

```
org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Connection closed unexpectedly
    at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.closed(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:139) [httpcore-nio-4.4.4.jar:4.4.4]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onClosed(InternalIODispatch.java:71) [httpasyncclient-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onClosed(InternalIODispatch.java:39) [httpasyncclient-4.1.1.jar:4.1.1]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.disconnected(AbstractIODispatch.java:102) [httpcore-nio-4.4.4.jar:4.4.4]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.sessionClosed(BaseIOReactor.java:281) [httpcore-nio-4.4.4.jar:4.4.4]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processClosedSessions(AbstractIOReactor.java:442) [httpcore-nio-4.4.4.jar:4.4.4]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:285) [httpcore-nio-4.4.4.jar:4.4.4]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:106) [httpcore-nio-4.4.4.jar:4.4.4]
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:590) [httpcore-nio-4.4.4.jar:4.4.4]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_72]
```

for a number of workers.

Comment: were you able to resolve it? i am getting the same exception.

Comment: I tried with `IOReactorConfig reactorConfig = IOReactorConfig.custom().setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT_5_MINS_IN_MILLIS)
    .setSoTimeout(TIMEOUT_5_MINS_IN_MILLIS).build();

  try (CloseableHttpAsyncClient asyncClient = HttpAsyncClients.custom().setDefaultIOReactorConfig(reactorConfig)
    .setDefaultHeaders(Collections.singletonList(oauthHeader)).setMaxConnPerRoute(MAX_CONN)
    .setMaxConnTotal(MAX_CONN).build();)` and the issue did not appear.

Comment: If this solution worked, answer yourself with the code, so will be more visibilit of the solution. There is a good explain of the situation in [this comment from HttpCore jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCORE-414?focusedCommentId=15011752&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-15011752).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @lucasvc, the default behaviour is explained [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCORE-414). Pertaining to my solution, the code was updated to the following and the issue did not appear.

```
IOReactorConfig reactorConfig = IOReactorConfig.custom()
        .setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT_5_MINS_IN‌​_MILLIS)
        .setSoTimeout(TIMEOUT_5_MINS_IN_MILLIS).build();

try (CloseableHttpAsyncClient asyncClient = HttpAsyncClients.custom()
        .setDefaultIOReactorConfig(reactorC‌​onfig)
        .setDefaultHeaders(Collections.singletonList(oauthHeader‌​))
        .setMaxConnPerRout‌​e(MAX_CONN)
        .setMaxConnTotal(MAX_CONN).build();) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: can you also add what is the value of your `MAX_CONN`? and, does this parameter matter here? Thanks @dmachop

Comment: @fluency03 Mine was 4 but you can assign the maximum connections that your client can handle. It depends on your requirement.

Comment: I saw people use 200 in total and 100 per route from an article.  Is it a reasonable number? Cause you are using 4.  What’s the machine you are running on?

Comment: Yes. Depends on your requirement and your machine configuration. I'm developing on a single CPU already loaded with short burst of threads and hence the low number. Also, take into consideration on how long the request will be processed. If it takes longer, it is advisable to have a powerful machine that can accommodate the responses else there would be a chance that the responses could time out.